# Can anyone help me decipher this html video code?

Tags: html, css, flash, video

I am working on a html project with video, and need to work with this video. I am hoping to apply two style

width: 550px;
controls preload="auto;

but am not sure where to place it. I need the video to preload due to its long loading time! Code examples have always shown a  tag, but this code does not have any.

```
<object id="flashObj" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
    <param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="videoId=3286763175001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fmedianetwork.oracle.com%2Fvideo%2Fplayer%2F3286763175001&playerID=1787102915001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAAFcSbzI~,OkyYKKfkn3xPOduPEsqhjskdCvDxqymz&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" />
    <param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" />
    <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashVars="videoId=3286763175001&linkBaseURL=http%3A%2F%2Fmedianetwork.oracle.com%2Fvideo%2Fplayer%2F3286763175001&playerID=1787102915001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAAAAFcSbzI~,OkyYKKfkn3xPOduPEsqhjskdCvDxqymz&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="640" height="358" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" swLiveConnect="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" style="width: 550px;"></embed>
</object>
```

If someone could please shorten and explain what some of the essential tags do that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `id` is the id of the element - `codebase`- is the source of the player -  `name` is the type of the source -  `value` is the source path of the file

Comment: Hope this link helps:

http://www.ist.rit.edu/~rpv/local/tutorials/embedding_video/

Answer (score 0):

id is the element of the video, the param tag helps to define the plugins with the element, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_param.asp , this gives a good example.